# Does `mup deploy`require to run `meteor npm install` before (locally)?

Tags: meteor, npm, npm-install, meteor-up

I have an app I like to deploy with meteor-up / mup.

In my packages.json I have babel-runtime listed:

```
{
  // .....
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.8"
  }
}
```

However, when I do `mup setup && mup deploy` I get this error:

```
Error: The babel-runtime npm package could not be found in your node_modules
directory. Please run the following command to install it:

  meteor npm install --save babel-runtime

    at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.babel-runtime.babel-runtime.js (packages/babel-runtime.js:36:9)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:197:9)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:120:16)
    at packages/babel-runtime.js:138:15
    at packages/babel-runtime.js:149:3
    at /built_app/programs/server/boot.js:303:34
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/built_app/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /built_app/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
    at /built_app/programs/server/boot.js:352:5
=> Starting meteor app on port:80
/built_app/programs/server/boot.js:356
}).run();
   ^
```

What I don't understand:

Do I have to run `meteor npm install` *locally* before I do `mup setup`?

Actually, I would expect that mup does this automatically while building and deploying the app.

I'm glad for any help to understand how this works!

Comment: Maybe, the error was caused by a mistake in the package.json, could it be that babel requires  `meteor npm install --save webpack@3`? Actually, do I _really_ need babel-core as dependency, shouldn't be the runtime sufficient?

Comment: In fact (for another little app) the deploy worked, after I _locally_ ran `meteor npm i` .... why? Doesn't mup exec npm install itself? What would happen if the server is a different architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `meteor npm install` before deploying because MeteorUp needs all npm dependencies to build the bundle on your computer.

Comment: Alright. How does it work if you have a differnt target platform and you have npm modules with binary stuff (e.g. bcrypt)?

Comment: The deploy scripts include recompiling binaries. You still need to install locally for mup to be able to run